# Why my onclick event not worked in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, onclick

it is my code:

```
<img src="images/pcal.png" onclick="displayDatePicker('MainPlaceHolder_txtDate');"
width="15" alt="" style="cursor: hand" />`
```

it dosen't work in Google Chrome

...

Comment: You forgot to paste in your code :)

Comment: Actually it was a formatting error. Then a question: your title says it doesn't work in Firefox and the question itself mentions Chrome. Which one do you mean? Or does it work in either at all?

Comment: What does the `displayDatePicker` function do?

Comment: yes,it work in either at all and my function 'displayDatePicker' display a my javaScript calender, it works just in IE!